# Fractional Matching version of Hall's Marriage theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, linear-programming

Let $G=(S,T,E)$ be a bipartite graph, $|S|=|T|$. Then the following are equivalent:

1) there exist a perfect matching in $G$;

2) there exist non-negative weights on edges such that the sum of weights of edges incident to each vertex equals 1 (in other words, there exists a Markov process which maps a uniform measure on $S$ to a uniform measure on $T$);

3) for any subset $S_1\subset S$, $S_1$ has at least $|S_1|$ neighbours in $T$.

Obviously, 1) implies 2) and 2) implies 3). My question is: does there exist a simple proof that 3) implies 2), avoiding proving 1)? The one I have in mind (with Hahn-Banach theorem, or linear programming duality if you prefer) is not any simpler.

Comment: Isn't this the essentially the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff.E2.80.93von_Neumann_theorem - the proof I know also uses 1).

Comment: @domotorp B-vN is $2\to 1$, is not it? I ask about $3\to 2$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: it would improve the question to change "Weak" to "Fractional" in the title, or even, more extensively, to call it "Fractional Matching Version of Hall's marriage theorem". "Fractional matching" is a usual term in matching theory, so the change of title would make the question blend better into the online literature.

Comment: That depends on the definition of simple. There is a simple proof of $3\Longrightarrow 1$ too (induction: if there is a proper subset $S_1\subset S$ with exactly $|S_1|$ neighbors (call that set of neighbors $T_1$), then $S_1,T_1$ and $S\setminus S_1,T\setminus T_1$ are also good pairs; if not, then we can take any edge $st$ and $S\setminus\{s\}, T\setminus\{t\}$ is a good pair). That is a three-liner. How much simpler do you want to make it?  Apparently, you are looking for something else than sheer simplicity but it is unclear what exactly...

Comment: @fedja well, I have to be more specific. This standard proof of Hall's theorem is short, but is not neither 'straightforward' nor 'algorithmic'. While the first claim is opinion-based, the second is rigorous: such inductive argument does not explain how to find a perfect matching in a graph satisfying Hall's conditions. In 17 camels question I reproduced an algorithm of Alon of finding a perfect matching in a regular bipartite multigraph, which is essentially any graph satisfying 2) (if the weights are rational, this is pretty the same.) (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation)  If we have a quick and clear way to find some such weights in any bipartite graph satisfying Hall's conditions, it could give a nice alternative approach to marriage theorem.

Comment: Possibly slightly longer, but straight-forward and algorithmic would be an interpretation as a maximum-flow problem (source on the left, sink on the right). This proves (3) -> (2) and has (1) as an 'accidental by-product' and not an intermediate step.
Condition (3) ensures that every cut has capacity at least |S|. The algorithm of Ford-Fulkerson then gives a method to generate a flow of strength |S|, which corresponds to a weighting as in (2).
By the design of the algorithm, it is clear that only integer values are ever used, so in fact (1) drops out immediately, but rather as a by-product.

Comment: This may be related: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07218